# Terminator and Zsh: ctrl+D not closing session

Tags: linux, linux-mint, zsh, oh-my-zsh, terminator

I've been a Terminator and zsh user for a while with consistent profiles across several machines.

However, on a freshly installed Linux Mint machine, for some reason Ctrl+D (EOT) isn't closing the window/tab/session/panel.

It appears to leave the z-session (i.e. dropping down to the next line on the console with no prompt) but the session is being 'kept alive' somehow instead of closing like it should.

Any ideas what's gone wrong?

**EDIT**: Tried in regular boring terminal / xterm and the same behaviour persists, so it's a zsh issue. .zsh config [here](https://gist.github.com/andrewbolster/8390679)

Comment: Does this also happen, when you didn't start any programs in the terminal? I know this behavior if I've run some X program over ssh in this terminal. `CTRL-C` usually terminates what-so-ever is still active in the background.

Comment: @mpy nope, open a new terminator instance (or terminal actually, so I guess it's a zsh problem) and ctrl-d doesn't have the intended effect.

Comment: Can you try without oh-my-zsh, i.e. do a `exec zsh -f` and try `CTRL-D` again.

Comment: @mpy Nope, same behaviour

Answer (score 5):

This behavior is definied with `setopt IGNORE_EOF` in your config file.

You can just remove this line and it should work.

If you need more info, check [this](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_16.html).

Comment: Fixes. I'm sorry, I don't know what I was doing, it was really late when I answered the question...

Comment: `unsetopt ignoreeof` also works. Add that to your ~/.zshrc